Caps lock inverted for normal and language-specific characters
Ubuntu 24.04: Sometimes my Caps lock state as indicated by the LED light on my Dell laptop keyboard gets inverted bot only for standard English characters. For special characters on my Czech keyboard (number keys on en keyboard), the Caps lock state matches the LED light.
I.e. writing without the Shift looks like this:
Caps lock light ON:     aaŠŠdddŽŽŽŽ
Caps lock light OFF:    AAššDDDžžžž

Restarting the machine fixes it, but it then can appear again - I don't have a definitive repro, but it appears that it is related to pressing Caps lock to wakeup from sleep mode and/or pressing Caps lock on the lock screen.
EDIT: Never using Caps lock when computer is suspended/locked has resulted in not seeing the problem at all.
Similar to, but different from Only can type in caps. It acts like the shift key is stuck and https://superuser.com/questions/1672217/the-capslock-functionaliy-is-reversed-in-ubuntu (notably all of the solutions there do not work for me, except for restarting the machine).
Specifically I've tried:

Alt / Ctrl / Shift + Caps lock in all combinations (including left/right)
Opening the screen keyboard and messing with it
Lock screen + unlock (plus pressing Caps lock in between)
Checking sticky keys (those are off)
Double tap Shift

I'd like to be able to prevent the situation/fix it without restarting.

I have the same issue. Based on your hint, I managed to intentionally fix it once this way:

trigger Suspend
wait until suspended
press CapsLock to wake up (couple of times)
type password & unlock.

